# Redis extension for PHP 5.6.3 Mac OSX

Tags: php, redis

I am using XAMPP PHP 5.6.3 on Mac OSx, I need to enable redis extension PHP. If you have any help urls please suggest me.

Comment: is redis already installed?

Comment: Redis server is installed, problem with redis extension I am not able to file proper redis.so file.

Comment: all installed .so modules is located in the /opt/lampp/modules folder. If you want to activate a extension, open your php.ini file in the etc/ folder add uncomment or add new line `extension="your-extension.so"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install extensions via xampp pecl:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/pecl install your-extension

sudo gedit /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini

// add line:

extension="your-extension.so"
```